# Loop between two lists until element match

Tags: python, list, loops

I want the `out_list` to loop until it found a match inside `in_list`. i did try to increase the index if the element mismatch to make the element in `out_list` match with coming `in_list`.

```
in_list = [1,2,2,1,3,4]
out_list = [1,2,3,2,1,4]

index = 0
for out in out_list:
    print(out, in_list[index])
    if out == in_list[index]:
        print('match')
        index = index + 1
    else:
        print('loop until match')
        index = index + 1
```

The first two element for `1` and `2` in both `in_list` and `out_list` will print 'match'. but the element for '3' should iterate until it found a match. but apparently it does not.

well the expected output would be always print 'match' as i want it to always loop until it find a match

Comment: you can use `enumerate` function for that, it'll be a lot more simple, and also seems like your code is working for me

Comment: @j1-lee well the expected output would be always print 'match' as i want it to always loop until it find a match

Comment: @j1-lee sorry my statement a bit confusing.  what i mean was, for example number 3 in out_list. i want the number 3 to find a match inside in_list. hence, the output that i wish to print out 'match' as number 3 will keep on looping until it find a match with in_list

Comment: You need two for loops. One for loop over `out_list`, as you did here; and another for loop **inside** the first for loop. This inner for loop should iterate over `in_list` until it finds a match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an answer, but are you expecting something like this? (Ignore the `print('\nNext Iteration in out_list:')` line, its just for debugging)

```py
in_list = [1,2,2,1,3,4]
out_list = [1,2,3,2,1,4]

for i in out_list:
    print('\nNext Iteration in out_list:')
    for j in in_list:
        print('  ', i, j, end=' ')
        if i == j:
            print('match')
            break
        print()
        # else:
        #     print('loop until match')
```

Output:

```json
Next Iteration in out_list:
   1 1 match

Next Iteration in out_list:
   2 1 
   2 2 match

Next Iteration in out_list:
   3 1 
   3 2 
   3 2 
   3 1 
   3 3 match

Next Iteration in out_list:
   2 1 
   2 2 match

Next Iteration in out_list:
   1 1 match

Next Iteration in out_list:
   4 1 
   4 2 
   4 2 
   4 1 
   4 3 
   4 4 match
```

Comment: thank you! got it. i tried using this way before but without the break statement. thanks ya!

Answer (score 0):

You can try with zip you can add break if you doesn't want the loop to continue after first match

```
in_list = [1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 4]
out_list = [1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 4]

for f, b in zip(in_list, out_list):
    if f == b:
        print("Element matched : " + str(f), str(b))
    else:
        print("Element Not-matched : " + str(f), str(b))
    


Element matched : 1 1
Element matched : 2 2
Element Not-matched : 2 3
Element Not-matched : 1 2
Element Not-matched : 3 1
Element matched : 4 4
```

Comment: thanks but i would want the number 3 to find his pair inside the in_list

Comment: Have edited the answer kindly check if this helps